# BigQuery loading JSON file: How to ignore a field or rename it?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON file on my computer and I would like to load it into a BigQuery table.
I have 3 keys in each lines. One of those is a timestamp: I would like to remove it and not get a "timestamp" column in my BigQuery table.
One of them has a wrong name: the name of the key in the JSON file is "special_id" but I would like to load it in a column named "main_id".
I can't find a way to do that while specifying the schema of the table created while loading. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

For that level of flexibility:

- Don't import as JSON
- Import as CSV (define null character as separator)
- Each line has only one column - the full JSON string
- Parse inside BigQuery with maximum flexibility (JSON parsing functions and even JS)